# Link in user actions for editing a teams page is borked

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, broken-link, old-teams

> [image: screenshot of user profile activity tab]

On the activity > actions > posts tab on a user profile, a SO teams page is counted as a "wiki", and apparently treated like a question. The link to the post is broken, linking to /questions/... instead of /teams/...

The text "wiki" should also probably be changed to "team page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next build will eliminate the teams creation from the user activity timeline.  We will be surfacing team actions in other ways in the long term.